# PHP Threading while doing multiple things

Tags: php

I'm writing a type of proxy in PHP.

This proxy will make a few connections to a server, and keep the connections open by sending a "ping" packet every so often if no other commands have to be sent.

A client should be able to connect to the proxy and have it forward a message onto the server. In that case, the proxy will pick one of the connections that is currently not busy (in case multiple clients connected and one of the requests is taking a while) and use that non-busy connection.

My idea on how it'd work: Use RabbitMQ as a queue. The client submits a message to RabbitMQ and waits for a response. On the server side, every connection would be its own thread, every thread would constantly be waiting for work from RabbitMQ, and the first one to get the message from RabbitMQ would fulfill the request. But in this case, since the connection thread is constantly busy waiting for work, how would I send the keepalive packet in case there isn't work?

If that's a bad idea, how would this be done properly?

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally, Threads are a great way to solve this problem, so you're definitely thinking about this problem the right way. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support Threads! So, you'll have to use *processes* instead via [`pcntl_fork()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). [Here's an example](https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-multithreaded-socket-server) (not my code), creating a new process to handle each connection instead of a thread.

```
/**
 * Connection handler
 */
function onConnect( $client ) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == -1) {
         die('could not fork');
    } else if ($pid) {
        // parent process
        return;
    }

    $read = '';
    printf( "[%s] Connected at port %d\n", $client->getAddress(), $client->getPort() );

    while( true ) {
        $read = $client->read();
        if( $read != '' ) {
            $client->send( '[' . date( DATE_RFC822 ) . '] ' . $read  );
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        if( preg_replace( '/[^a-z]/', '', $read ) == 'exit' ) {
            break;
        }
        if( $read === null ) {
            printf( "[%s] Disconnected\n", $client->getAddress() );
            return false;
        }
        else {
            printf( "[%s] recieved: %s", $client->getAddress(), $read );
        }
    }
    $client->close();
    printf( "[%s] Disconnected\n", $client->getAddress() );

}
require "sock/SocketServer.php";
$server = new \Sock\SocketServer();
$server->init();
$server->setConnectionHandler( 'onConnect' );
$server->listen();
```

You said that you also need a Thread to send keepalives. I would say the simplest solution would be to `pnctl_fork()` one additional process and use it to send keepalives, while the other processes are busy.

As for keepalive messages, you could do this in the forked connection handler process. Then, do the actual work in yet another forked process underneath the connection handler process.

Comment: Note that this is a very broad question, so it's hard to be much more specific with an answer.

Comment: Ok - I've read about pcntl_fork() as well. But wouldn't that thread only last as long as my client was connected to the proxy? Eg, my client connects -> a new process is started to handle the client -> client disconnects -> process ends.

Comment: Well the process wouldn't automatically die when the client disconnects. If the client is going to disconnect before the work is complete, then maybe the worker process pools should be completely separate, and clients just interact with a queue that the background worker processes consume.

Comment: The process has to remain open indefinitely to keep the connections open/send keep-alive packets. In the case of a queue, though, how would the thread check the queue as well as send the keep-alive packets?